# Getting dynamically created ion-input value in IONIC2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I  have  the  following  HTML  part  in  which `ion-item`  is  created  dynamically based  on `*ngFor`

```
<ion-list *ngIf="Label_view">

  <ion-item style="Float:Right;margin-left: 4%;" *ngFor="let bil of arr_label;let i=index ">
    <ion-label floating>{{bil}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="array" id={{i}}  type="text"  maxlength="5"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Register

I  have  to  get values  of `ion-input`  into  `component` .I  have  used `[(ngModel)]` value  to  bind  to  array.

My  component side

```
array:any[]=[];

Blr_regis()
{
    console.log( array);
  //  console.log(document.getElementById("1").Value);
    var x=document.getElementById("1").Value;
   console.log(x);
}
```

I'm getting  UNDEFINED as  console  Output.
Is  there something  am  missing?

Comment: You are getting undefined because you put an array as an ngmodel. It should be a string or a number. Like [(ngModel)]="bil.Id"

Comment: Thank you..:)  @misha130

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're trying to bind an Array with the input element. It should be bound to a string or a number (or **a single position of the array**).

Instead of doing something like this:

```
  <ion-item style="Float:Right;margin-left: 4%;" *ngFor="let bil of arr_label;let i=index ">
    <ion-label floating>{{bil}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="array" id={{i}}  type="text"  maxlength="5"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

And having those two `let` in the `*ngFor`, why don't you put everything together in the same array like this:

```
this.newArray : Array<{id: number, value: string}> = [];

// Assuming the `arr_label` exists and it has been properly initialized
for(let i=0; i < arr_label.length; i++) {
    this.newArray.push({ id: i, value: arr_label[i] });
}
```

And then in your view:

```
  // We only iterate over the newArray because all the information we need is there
  <ion-item style="Float:Right;margin-left: 4%;" *ngFor="let bill of newArray">

    <ion-label floating>{{bill.value}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="array[bill.id]" type="text" maxlength="5"></ion-input>

  </ion-item>
```

Notice we're now binding the `input` to a single position of the array, using the `id` (which would be 0, 1, and so on).

You can find a working [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VipAKxNcWmBssxtjrO5H?p=preview). Take a look at the code in `Page1.ts` and `Page1.html`